# Can AWS API Gateway Lambda Authorizer grant resources to access S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have an **AWS API Gateway Lambda Authorizer** that constructs a policy based on the **users permissions**. Currently it allows this particular user to execute the GET /users endpoint:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:{region}:{aws-id}:{api-id}/*/GET/users",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would also like the lambda function which is executed to be able to perform a GetObject action on my s3 bucket, any ideas why the following doesn't work:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:{region}:{aws-id}:{api-id}/*/GET/users",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket-name}/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

The key here is that these permissions are user-specific and so i was hoping to construct the permission for each endpoint as per the users permissions.

Comment: My understanding is that the returned policy indicates which API actions are allowed. It says nothing about other AWS resources (such as S3 buckets). More [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/a3hoab/using_aws_lambdaapi_gateway_to_authenticate/). And specifically, the policy returned is *not* the policy that the eventual Lambda function assumes.

Comment: i think you are right, would you know how to assign an iam policy to a lambda function dynamically?

Comment: You can't. What I think you'd have to do is give the Lambda function a policy that allows it to assume certain other IAM roles (and maybe that's its only set of permissions other than basic execution role to allow logging). The Lambda function itself can then infer which of the pre-configured IAM roles it should assume from the context of the client request.